# css Another case of filling remaining height but a special one

Tags: css

I've been looking for an answer all day.. Went thru a lot of similar SO question, but didn't find one that fits this situation (**variable height** means height that's determined by content):
[image]

Is it possible to do without this kind of JS (full example http://jsfiddle.net/RBE54)

```
document.getElementById('rightBox2').style.height = 
  (document.getElementById('rightSide').offsetHeight - 
   document.getElementById('rightBox1').offsetHeight
  ) + 'px';
```

while keeping all margins, rounded corners, and support for at least IE8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) model.

But I really should mention that browser support for FlexBox is inconsistent at the moment.

Comment: yes, thanks. that pushed me to edit the question by adding IE8 there